# Software for creating a USB drive presentation

Tags: usb, presentation, launcher

Recently I was asked to create a "interactive presentation" that could be put on a USB drive that would be given away at a company event. The presentation would either launch automatically or be opened manually from the drive itself.

Years ago I used to create Flash projector files on CD's that would launch when the CD was inserted into the drive. But I am not sure what the modern equivalent is for USB drives?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What OS? What price? [Edit] your question

Comment: Take a look at [Prezi](http://prezi.com/). Their 'Pro' plan lets you work offline. I'm not sure about the possibility to autostart.

Comment: Can you be a bit more detailed? What do you mean by interactive? Can the user click links & alter the flow of presentation (HTML-like)? Just a slide-show? For something like a PowerPoint presentation, you could use portable Libre Office

Comment: A bootable live linux with libreoffice (in ISO form) you can put on to a USB stick with unetbootin or similiar and copy your presenatation on there and it is all self contained.

Comment: @Jan Doggen - Both Mac & Windows.

Comment: @Mawg - by interactive it would be like a mini application with videos, audio and links to view PDF files (which would also be on the USB).

Comment: @cybernard - thanks for the tip, I will look into that.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest and most portable solution would be to create your interactive presentation as a mini-web site, with local relative links, images and possibly sounds. Then simply put the whole minisite on the USB drives. If there is a file called index.html in the root directory of the drive a lot of computers will automatically open it.

You can have automatic transitions between pages based on time, transitions based on clicking links, images, parts of images the lot.

- Should work on any computer that has a web browser, (check it for working on multiple browsers).
- Cross Platform
- No software to install
- Unlikely to trigger virus alerts
- Very flexible
- Can include links to the company website or other resources
- Familiar user interface

There are lots of web page creators out there but you can use [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/) Impress to make a presentation and export it as a html document.

Comment: Yes that is definitely the easiest solution, but the client would prefer something that didn't open in the web browser. They'd prefer it to be a self-contained application (basically like a Flash projector) with its own icon that a user can see when they open the USB and double-click to run.